# Is it possible to apply condition inside the map function of Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I wanted to apply some condition in foodOrders. Is it possible to apply condition inside map function that acts as where $foodOrder->foodOrders->where('invoice_id',null)->get();

```
 public function getTableList(Request $request){
    $skip =$request->skip;
    $limit=$request->limit;
    $totaltable = Table::get()->count();

    $table = Table::skip($skip)->take($limit)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    $table->map(function($foodOrder){
        $foodOrder->foodOrders;
    });
}
```

Below is the output that this query returns. But I only want the data with null invoice_id

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Lists of Table.",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "table_number": "TN02",
            "food_orders": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "food_items_id": 1,
          "table_id": 2,
          "invoice_id": null,
          "quantity": 2,
          "price": "2000.00"
         },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "food_items_id": 2,
          "table_id": 2,
          "invoice_id": null,
          "quantity": 3,
          "price": "150.00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "table_number": "TN01",
      "created_at": "2020-10-25 10:44:31",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-25 10:44:31",
      "food_orders": [
        {
          "id": 14,
          "food_items_id": 1,
          "table_id": 1,
          "invoice_id": 39,
          "quantity": 1,
          "price": "2000.00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best approach, bu this should do the trick

```
$table->map(function($foodOrder){
    $foodOrder->foodOrders=$foodOrder->foodOrders()->where('invoice_id',null)->get();
});
```

Note the scopes, you need them to apply where condition. And we say `=` so the further changes are propagated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is a `filter` and not a `map`. Or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the whitelisted records for the food_orders.

```php
$table->map(function($record){
    $record->food_orders = collect($record->food_orders)
        ->filter(fn($foodOrder) => is_null($foodOrder->invoice_id));

   return $record;
});
```

From the output data you have shown above it seems that the food_orders is a hasMany relation on the model, so it would be easy to filter out the relation when eager loading

Assuming that Table model has a relation defined for food_orders

```php
class Table extends Model
{
    public function food_orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FoodOrder::class);
    }

    //... rest of the class code
}
```

You can constrain the related models when eager loading

```php
$table = Table::with([
        'food_orders' => fn($query) => $query->whereNull('invoice_id')
    ])
    ->skip($skip)
    ->take($limit)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```